# Ads not working in WP7 emulator

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am using following code in my `WP7` app to display the dummy ad by `Microsoft`. When I run the emulator, no ad is shown. What is wrong here ?

```
 <my:AdControl AdUnitId="Image480_80" ApplicationId="test_client" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,550,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to http://advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps

Register your App, then you have to add the following to your control:
AdUnitId="" 
ApplicationId=""

Your code as it stands now is just displaying a placeholder.

FYI I found that ads sometimes do not work on the emulator.